# Java - JTable selecting first column by default

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection, mouselistener

I have this piece of code:

```
listTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                  if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                  JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();

                  int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                  int column = target.getSelectedColumn();

                  String title = listTable.getValueAt(row, column).toString();
                  String duration = listTable.getValueAt(row, column+1).toString();
                  String genre = listTable.getValueAt(row, column+2).toString();
                  String actor = listTable.getValueAt(row, column+3).toString();
                  String director = listTable.getValueAt(row, column+4).toString();
                  //String rentable = listTable.getValueAt(row, column+5).toString();
                  //String synopsis = listTable.getValueAt(row, column+6).toString();

                  txtTitle.setText(title);
                  txtDuration.setText(duration);
                  txtGenre.setText(genre);


                  }
                });
```

Which enables me:

- When a row is selected it passes the values in the columns to JTextBoxes.

However, when I don't click the first column by default, the selection gets garbled up. For example, if I don't click on the "Title" column first and click on the "Duration" column, it puts the duration in txtTitle and the others are also mixed up.

How do I add a piece of code that when a row is selected, it default-selects the first column ?

This is a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than forcing selection of column why not always extract values based on known columns?

For example you can replace:

```
String title = listTable.getValueAt(row, column).toString();
```

with:

```
String title = listTable.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
```

If you provide ability to reorder columns then you can instead try `table.getModel().getValueAt(convertRowIndextoModel(row), 0);`

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
```

to

```
int column = 0;
```

Your version gets the column index from where the user clicked, you need the first one (index 0)

Comment: Thanks ! I knew it was something simple!

Comment: If the columns are dragged arround you need to use the model's getValueAt() please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Everything depends how is set ListSelectionModel, but works for me

```
myTable.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its obvious, as When you click on Duration Column

`int column = target.getSelectedColumn();`

gets the column value of Duration and thus

```
String title = listTable.getValueAt(row, column).toString();
```

gets the value from the duration column..
the best way to tackle this is hard code column no.
Suppose your Table is in Following Order
Title : column 0
Duration : Column 1
Genre : Column 2 and so on

simply put `String title = listTable.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();`

```
String duration = listTable.getValueAt(row,1).toString();
```

and so on..!!

Hope it helps